# Osrm invalid url

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, osrm

I'm getting the following error when i hit my server Url

my request:  curl 'http://52.66.253.182/osrm/nearest?loc=73.920239,18.5649413'

```
{"message":"URL string malformed close to position 1: \"\/\/ne\"","code":"InvalidUrl"}
```

I think it's something related to my nginx server conf file 
here's my conf file code :

```
 upstream osrm {
    server 0.0.0.0:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 52.66.253.182;

    location /osrm {
        proxy_pass http://osrm/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

### [Browser resposne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYjq3.png)

I'm able to run it on localhost .

my Request : `curl 'http://localhost:5000/route/v1/driving/73.9635837,18.5330435;74.0200603,18.5454127'`

Response : `{"code":"Ok","routes":[{"geometry":"mkbpByambM|e@xDIul@tKkf@pJeNGwTmJ{NuHoBXkIrBkGoIcIsD\\gD{Bk@aEfBsAoFyJ}[oDgc@yI_oAgMdFoX|Eyj@v@}}@","legs":[{"steps":[],"distance":9577.3,"duration":883.7,"summary":"","weight":883.7}],"distance":9577.3,"duration":883.7,"weight_name":"routability","weight":883.7}],"waypoints":[{"hint":"Ji2DgCktg4AAAAAAJgAAAAAAAADQAwAAAAAAABNd1EEAAAAAvawpRAAAAAAmAAAAAAAAANADAAD4AgAAwJloBMnDGgFAmGgEtMoaAQAAjwsvU8Mk","name":"","location":[73.963968,18.531273]},{"hint":"dwQogM0IdYAAAAAANAAAAPgLAACOBAAAAAAAAMSZD0KaBQVFm1qERAAAAAA0AAAA-AsAAI4EAAD4AgAA8HRpBMUIGwHcdGkEBfsaASkAnwUvU8Mk","name":"","location":[74.02008,18.548933]}]}`

Comment: Try: `location /osrm/`

Comment: Thank you @RichardSmith Its working now .